# Add a custom walker to a menu created in a widget

Tags: menus, widgets, walker

I know how to add a Walker to a custom menu created by the theme (menu named `primary` in this example), but how can I target a menu thats created in a widget with the default wordpress custom menu widget?

```
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {

$args = array(
    'menu' => 'main-menu',
    'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'depth' => 0,
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'nav',
    'walker' => new Myprefix_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
    'echo' => 0
);

$nav = wp_nav_menu( $args );

}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at implementation of `WP_Nav_Menu_Widget` class you will see the following code:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    // Get menu
    $nav_menu = ! empty( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] ) : false;

    if ( !$nav_menu )
        return;

    $instance['title'] = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
        echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

    wp_nav_menu( array( 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu' => $nav_menu ) );

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

It means that there is no any chance to hook a menu. So you need to take a look at `wp_nav_menu` function implementation, where you can find following lines of code:

```
$defaults = array(
  'menu' => '',
  'container' => 'div',
  'container_class' => '',
  'container_id' => '',
  'menu_class' => 'menu',
  'menu_id' => '',
  'echo' => true,
  'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
  'before' => '',
  'after' => '',
  'link_before' => '',
  'link_after' => '',
  'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
  'depth' => 0,
  'walker' => '',
  'theme_location' => ''
);

$args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
$args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
$args = (object) $args;
```

Here you can see that all arguments passed to the `wp_nav_menu` function could be replaced. So what you need is to create your own hook handler which will add your walker to a navigation menu. It could be simple as:

```
function myplugin_custom_walker( $args ) {
    return array_merge( $args, array(
        'walker' => new My_Custom_Walker(),
        // another setting go here ... 
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'myplugin_custom_walker' );
```

Comment: this is great thank you. Looks like this makes the default for all menus. Am I right to assume that when i use this i am stuck with all menus having this walker? because i tryed `'walker' => new Walker_Nav_Menu()` in the arguments of my specific menu to override it again to become the wordpress default walker for just one menu, but sadly this don't works.

Comment: @amy yes it will be default for all menus.

Comment: @amy you can include code to examine the args. Then put an if conditional whether you apply the walker or not.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @Eugene's answer, if you want to limit this to a specific menu, just check the term ID of the menu:

```
function custom_nav_args($args){
$menu = $args['menu'];
    if($menu->term_id === 17)  /* replace term_id with menu id, or use $menu->name to do it by menu name*/
    {
        $args['walker'] = new My_Custom_Walker();
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'custom_nav_args');
```

Comment: How would we filter by sidebar id?

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to targeting a menu by `term_id` and I thought it might be of use to someone as a way of modifying several menus without having to look up their ids.

By adding `print_r($args)` to a filter, I noticed that `$args['menu']` is a string for menus in predefined theme locations and `WP_Term_Object` for a custom menu widget in a sidebar.

I used this to target menus by slug and add a class to their container. A number of menus can be targeted by including a common string in their slugs. Note: menu slug comes from the array key in `register_nav_menus()`.

```
function my_menu_thingy( $args ) {
  if( is_object($args['menu']) && strpos($args['menu']->{slug},'my-common-string') !== false ) {
    $args['walker'] = new My_Custom_Walker();
  }
  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_menu_thingy' );
```

For a single menu you would just need to check that `$args['menu']->{slug} == 'your-slug'` instead of the strpos() bit above.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom walker to a nav menu created in a widget using the `widget_nav_menu_args` filter added in wordpress `4.2.0`. It accepts four arguments (see `wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-nav-menu-widget.php`). But to add only a custom walker you just need to use the first argument, the same way you use the `wp_nav_menu_args` filter.

```
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_args'); //for menus
    add_filter('widget_nav_menu_args', 'my_args'); //for menus in widgets
    function my_args($args) { //$args is only argument needed to add custom walker
       return array_merge( $args, array(
          'walker' => new My_Custom_Walker(),
       ) );
    }
```